# How to read username and password separately from web.config in C#

Tags: c#

```
<add key="DBconnection" 
     value="USER=harc, PASSWORD=imp, FOR_USER=ra005" />
```

I have this line of config in my `web.config`.

I am getting this value in my C# code as

```
string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBconnection"];
```

How do I get the USER and PASSWORD values individually from this configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't need to parse a connection string.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: you could just store username and password separately, then build your connection string at run time

Comment: - web.config is just an XML file
- that connection string has those values in it, you can string parse them out if you like, but that's not wise.
- you can always store username and password as separate properties in the config elsewhere

Comment: I should not make a new entry for username and password seperately. I need to get them from the existing configuration.

Comment: string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBconnection"];

Comment: string[] values = connect.Split(',');

Comment: This will give a string array with USER=har, PASSWORD = imp, FOR_USER=ra005

Comment: how do I get the user value here seperately

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a SQL Server connection string, pass it to a [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder):

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBconnection"]
);
// use builder.UserID and builder.Password here
```

If it's a connection string for another database, you'll have to know the proper provider -- or store it as a `<connectionString>` so the provider is included.

Note that actually including a user ID and password as plain text in a configuration setting is not recommended. See [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms254494), especially the section "Encrypting Configuration File Sections Using Protected Configuration".

Answer (score 0):

You can add key value pair in webconfig file

```
<add key="UserName" value="test" />
<add key="Password" value="test" />
```

and read it like `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]`